# Fast Way to Grep Multiple Keywords on Mulitiple Corpus

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have list of 13K terms which I want to identify it's presence in 24K text files.
So finally I'd like to have `terms->file names` context.

What's the best way to achieve this using Unix/bash commands?

I can use Perl script like this but too slow:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#....skip...
foreach my $term (@terms) {
    system("grep $term /corpus/*.txt/")
}
```

Comment: look for info on `fgrep -f terms` and `find` with `xargs`. you may need to use `grep -F -f terms` depending on your version. You may need to recompile `fgrep` to have a big enough buffer to take in all of your targets. Yes, or use the GNU-style long arguments to a modern grep per @Perleone 's answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep --fixed-strings --word-regexp --with-filename --file=terms.txt --recursive /corpus
```